# Unable to connect to MYSQL from Docker Instance

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to `Docker` and pulled the `mysql` from the **docker hub** using following command

```
docker pull mysql
```

Now, started `mysql` instance using following commands.

```
docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
Unable to find image 'mysql/mysql-server:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from mysql/mysql-server

e64f6e679e1a: Pull complete
799d60100a25: Pull complete
85ce9d0534d0: Pull complete
d3565df0a804: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:59a5854dca16488305aee60c8dea4d88b68d816aee627de022b19d9bead48d04
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql/mysql-server:latest
1be4f5dde2fb4e1d99e23ee2de5e3b663c7c2d0fabe7ef459cf87385071a2e0d
```

Now, I've checked what all services are up and running.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                               NAMES
1be4f5dde2fb        mysql/mysql-server:latest   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
e7d9e3713f5c        ubuntu                      "/bin/bash"              6 days ago          Up 6 days                                                    angry_hodgkin
```

and now I execute the following commands and unable to connect to mysql -

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -ppassword -uroot
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Docker version..

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

*Now, I'm getting below erro - EDIT-1*

```
docker exec -it 1be4f5dde2fb bash
bash-4.2# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
bash-4.2# sudo mysql
bash: sudo: command not found
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: `mysql: command not found`: you need to install the MySQL client tools on your host.

Comment: @DavidMaze - How can we do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get in the docker container using the following command

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

You can then easily connect to MySQL, by executing the following command

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

If you are trying to connect from the host machine, then you will have to install the `mysql` client.
On mac, the command is as follows

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: I am getting `bash-4.2# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
bash-4.2# sudo mysql
bash: sudo: command not found
bash-4.2#`   Why should we use `brew instal mysql` as I'm already using mysql image and its running? How to connect to it ?

Comment: You have installed MySQL server container. To connect it from the command line, you will have to do it from within the container.

docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep GENERATED - Run this command outside the container. You will get the password..

You can connect using the following command 
    mysql -u root -p

Use the password from 1st command shared.

Instructions : https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: I execute `docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep GENERATED`, but it doesn't gave me anything

Comment: Once you get in the container, you can execute the following command
mysql -uroot -p {Hit enter and type password when it prompts to}. Share error if any

Comment: @PAA: You can also go into docker instance using: `docker exec -it mysql bash`, will be easier to remember.

Comment: yes sir thanks ! I will try to connect to Redis as well, simillar fashion !