# Unable to connect to Mysql hosted on Docker on Windows machine

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I already executed mentioned here: [Unable to connect to MYSQL from Docker Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582401/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-from-docker-instance), but this time I'm running docker on windows machine.

```
pc@DESKTOP-NQ639DU MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker pull mysql/mysql-server
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from mysql/mysql-server
e64f6e679e1a: Pull complete
799d60100a25: Pull complete
85ce9d0534d0: Pull complete
d3565df0a804: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:59a5854dca16488305aee60c8dea4d88b68d816aee627de022b19d9bead48d04
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql/mysql-server:latest

pc@DESKTOP-NQ639DU MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
79ff1c03452ab2eac0d798b576ffeabde24d4c5aa6954d3d5c5bef99dcc40ce8

pc@DESKTOP-NQ639DU MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ mysql -uroot -ppassword
bash: mysql: command not found

pc@DESKTOP-NQ639DU MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker exec -it mysql bash
bash-4.2# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
bash-4.2# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
bash-4.2#
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect through the loopback interface, as you don't have access to the socket.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

In this case, it's like if your server is running on another machine, this only thing share with your host machine is the exposed port.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the MySQL client from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/ then you'll be able to access the Docker-hosted MySQL in the same way you'd access any other MySQL database (of note without needing to get a root shell in the database container).  Since you're using Docker Toolbox you'd probably use 192.168.99.100 as the IP address of the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below in docker-compose.y\ml

```
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
         MYSQL_DATABASE: 'Dbname'
         # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
         MYSQL_USER: 'username'
         # You can use whatever password you like
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'Password'
         # Password for root access
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'RootPassword'
        ports:
         # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
          - '3307:3306'
        expose:
         # Opens port 3306 on the container
          - '3306'
         # Where our data will be persisted
        volumes:
        - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    volumes:
      my-db:
```